# AWS ec2 web app goes down when command prompt is closed

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I ssh into the ec2 instance using command prompt. I then launch the jar file from there. The web app runs perfectly from any device until the command prompt is closed. The site immediately goes down. The instance is shown as “running” when the site is down. ideas?

Comment: you can find the long answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148698) how to run your jar when the terminal is closed.  But if you dont want to do it in a proper way do it via [How to start a jar file using systemd](https://serverfault.com/a/944119) instead of running the command directly via shell.

Answer (score 1):

Well, ec2 is the virtual machine and it will show as running because you didn't shutdown or terminate it.

Your webapp is down because closing the command prompt will quit the shell session and thus terminating/killing the running jar.

It seems you are not running the jar as a background process.

If you are using Linux EC2 instance then try running your jar as

```
$java -jar jarfilename.jar &
```

The & makes your java process as a background job.

Note down the process id and then close the session. Now your webapp will keep on running as long as your ec2 instance is running.

I'd suggest reading about nohup and background processes in Linux in general.

Comment: I really appreciate the response. so I tried this it did not work :(

Comment: can you paste the command you are running after ssh?

Comment: ssh -i “directory to pem file” ec2-user@“public IP”

Comment: after that: java -jar “jar file name” &

Comment: try
nohup java -jar "jar file name" &

Comment: java -jar jarfilename.jar & didnot work